# Репликация DNS записей с удаленного сервиса

Tags: windows, dns, windows-server

Есть "DNS-провайдер" хостинга в интернете. Там 100 с лишним записей. Подняли windows-dns для внутренних нужд (Win 2016). Есть ли быстрый способ скопировать все записи для определенного домена (а не забивать ручками)?

Comment: Для начала вам надо разрешить передачу зоны с той DNS где сейчас зона. Как это может делаться через web-интерфейс не представляю. посмотрите там что нибудь по поводу "передача зоны", "AXFR" или чего то подобного. Без этого никакие простые пути не заработают и придется переносить руками. И скажите какие типы/режимы зон бывают в Win-DNS. Учитывая, что вряд ли вы захотите что бы ваш сервер поддерживал эту зону в интернете вам нужен тип зоны cache или hint (но это в терминах bind, как оно в винде я не знаю). так же посмотрите умеет ли ваш сервер загружать описание зоны из текстового файла.

Comment: Единственный способ – написать парсер для веб-интерфейса.

Comment: @Alex78191 Почему "единственный". многие компании поддерживающие сервера DNS сейчас имеют API для операций с доменами. Если на какой то IP прописать в зоне NS запись, то они просто обязаны на этот ip начать отдавать зону по AXFR, а тогда ее можно целиком будет забрать каким нибудь `dig`. А если они никому не отдают зону ни в каком виде - то бежать надо от таких dns-провайдеров

Comment: Zerginwan, кстати, скажите какой "DNS-провайдер", может по нему кто нибудь что нибудь конкретное сможет сказать

Comment: Если DNS-провайдер не поддерживает этого, то единственный.

Comment: Mike, 1gb.ru
Решил изначально не писать, ибо скрытая реклама, вот это все.

Comment: API у них в принципе есть https://www.1gb.ru/api-doc/ только он какой то странный, DNS можно редактировать, но получить текущий вроде как нельзя. А вы не пробовали связаться с поддержкой и описать вашу проблему ?

Comment: Видимо буду копировать в блокнот и писать powershell скрипт по добавлению записей из файла

Answer (score 1):

Если вы не можете получить эту информацию от DNS (например, у вас нет прав), то одной из альтернатив является использование [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).

1. Введите домен в поле поиска и запустите поиск. Пример: google.com
2. В 3-ей секции сверху (под названием "Web statistics for all of google.com") нажмите кнопку "Subdomains"
3. В разделе Subdomains нажмите кнопку "More"

Вы сможете увидеть список поддоменов. Внизу есть кнопка Plaintext, с помощью которой этот список можно сохранить. Хотя я подозреваю, что он не показывает всех поддоменов.

Comment: Похоже раздел web statistics там появляется только если где то есть эта самая статистика. далеко не по всем доменам вообще есть блок. И да, список субдоменов ... ну скажем так, он только по тем суюдоменам на которых подняты web-сервера и на которых ведется та самая статистика.

Comment: Plaintext'ом я могу скопировать с сайта.

Comment: @Zerginwan в чем тогда проблема? Напишите скрипта для добавления DNS записей.

Answer (score 1):

Выгрузите в файл, а затем на сервере DNS у себя по пути c:\windows\system32\dns отредактируйте файл с новыми записями [источник](http://pyatilistnik.org/kak-nastroit-dns-server-v-windows-server-2012r2-2-chast-nastroyka-dopolnitelnoy-zonyi-sozdanie-i-nastroyka-zaglushki/)

Answer (score 0):

Напишите краулер для веб-интерфейса DNS-провайдера.

Если есть доступ к DNS серверу провайдера, то можно использовать способ [передача зоны DNS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_DNS), но это должно быть разрешено DNS сервером.

Вам необходимо в windows server включить и разрешить передачу зоны для зоны, которую вы хотите перенести. Вы можете настроить это на вкладке «Zone Transfers» на страницах свойств зоны.

Comment: К сожалению, у меня нет доступа к настройкам DNS-сервера хостинга. Т.е. я могу добавлять или изменять там DNS-записи, но в сам механизм доступ, очевидно, закрыт. Я так же практиччески уверен, что у них там не Windows DNS, а что-то линуксоподобное.

Comment: @Zerginwan обновил

Comment: @Mike потому в вики, написано, что вытесняется другими.

Comment: Любопытно. Интересно какими. bind 9 ничего другого до сих пор не умеет. И главное, в самом протоколе DNS других не предусмотрено, значит имеются ввиду передачи за кулисами DNS. Ну да, если зоны например в БД  то репликация такой БД скорее всего будет более быстрым способом